# How to put clicked item of input list inside of search input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I already created my searchable input but when I select one item of the input list it doesn't put inside of the input, it doesn't select really, how can I do that? I really don't know-how

I tried using `onclick` and trying like a put a value for the input when didn't work too

It should look like this when you select one item of the list should be displayed inside the input and closed the list, closing the list is something more easiest with a display none but I couldn't make the function of putting the word inside

https://www.screencast.com/t/9o6LFihuo

```css
#search-box
{
   border-style:none;
}

.divider-border{
    border-right: 2px solid #DFD6D6!important ;
    height: auto;
}

.search-radius{
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px !important; 
    height: 3rem;
    background: #EEEEEE ;
}

.btn-default{
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px !important;
    background: #EEEEEE ;
}

input[type=search]:focus {
    outline:none !important;
    outline-width: 0 !important;
    background: white !important;
    box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}

input:focus ~ .btn-default {
    background: white !important;
}

  .btn:focus,.btn:active {
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none;
 }

 
 input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    font-weight: 700;
    background : url("images/baseline_clear_black_18dp.png") ;
 }

 .results {
    /* Remove default list styling */
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .results li a {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    padding: 12px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    display: block
  }

  #myUL{
    display: none;
  }
 
#myInput {
    background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png'); /* Add a search icon to input */
    background-position: 10px 12px; /* Position the search icon */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the icon image */
    width: 100%; /* Full-width */
    font-size: 16px; /* Increase font-size */
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px; /* Add some padding */
    border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
    margin-bottom: 12px; /* Add some space below the input */
  }
  
  #myUL {
    /* Remove default list styling */
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  #myUL li a {
    border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a border to all links */
    margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
    background-color: #f6f6f6; /* Grey background color */
    padding: 12px; /* Add some padding */
    text-decoration: none; /* Remove default text underline */
    font-size: 18px; /* Increase the font-size */
    color: black; /* Add a black text color */
    display: block; /* Make it into a block element to fill the whole list */
  }
  
  #myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
    background-color: #eee; /* Add a hover effect to all links, except for headers */
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Our css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Emails View</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">

            <section class="col-10" id="content">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Searchbar -->
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="input-group mt-4">
                            <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
                                <ul id="myUL" class="dropdown-menu col-12" role="menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
            
                                    <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
            
                                    <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            
                            <input type="search" class="form-control search-radius" onkeyup="myFunction()" name="search-template" placeholder="Search or select template " id="search-box">
                            <span class="divider-border"></span>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                    
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /Searchbar -->
                
                  </div>
        
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
      // Declare variables
      var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
      input = document.getElementById('search-box');
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
      li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
    
      // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
</script>
<script>
    $('#search-box').on('input', function() {
        $('#myUL').css('display', $(this).val()  !== '' ? 'block' : 'none')
    });
</script>

<script>
        $('button').click(function () { // on a click on botton
            $('#myUL').show(); // show the div with the search results
            $('#myUL').css({
                'margin-left' : -$('#search-box').outerWidth( true )
            });
        })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create and bind another function which handles the click event on each items. It transfers the selected item and close the list.

```css
#search-box
{
   border-style:none;
}

.divider-border{
    border-right: 2px solid #DFD6D6!important ;
    height: auto;
}

.search-radius{
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px !important; 
    height: 3rem;
    background: #EEEEEE ;
}

.btn-default{
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px !important;
    background: #EEEEEE ;
}

input[type=search]:focus {
    outline:none !important;
    outline-width: 0 !important;
    background: white !important;
    box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}

input:focus ~ .btn-default {
    background: white !important;
}

  .btn:focus,.btn:active {
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none;
 }

 
 input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    font-weight: 700;
    background : url("images/baseline_clear_black_18dp.png") ;
 }

 .results {
    /* Remove default list styling */
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .results li a {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    padding: 12px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    display: block
  }

  #myUL{
    display: none;
  }
 
#myInput {
    background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png'); /* Add a search icon to input */
    background-position: 10px 12px; /* Position the search icon */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the icon image */
    width: 100%; /* Full-width */
    font-size: 16px; /* Increase font-size */
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px; /* Add some padding */
    border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
    margin-bottom: 12px; /* Add some space below the input */
  }
  
  #myUL {
    /* Remove default list styling */
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  #myUL li a {
    border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a border to all links */
    margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
    background-color: #f6f6f6; /* Grey background color */
    padding: 12px; /* Add some padding */
    text-decoration: none; /* Remove default text underline */
    font-size: 18px; /* Increase the font-size */
    color: black; /* Add a black text color */
    display: block; /* Make it into a block element to fill the whole list */
  }
  
  #myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
    background-color: #eee; /* Add a hover effect to all links, except for headers */
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Our css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Emails View</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">

            <section class="col-10" id="content">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Searchbar -->
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="input-group mt-4">
                            <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
                                <ul id="myUL" class="dropdown-menu col-12" role="menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
            
                                    <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
            
                                    <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            
                            <input type="search" class="form-control search-radius" onkeyup="myFunction()" name="search-template" placeholder="Search or select template " id="search-box">
                            <span class="divider-border"></span>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                    
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /Searchbar -->
                
                  </div>
        
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById('search-box');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
    
    // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

$('#search-box').on('input', function() {
    $('#myUL').css('display', $(this).val()  !== '' ? 'block' : 'none')
});

$('button').click(function () { // on a click on botton
    $('#myUL').show(); // show the div with the search results
    $('#myUL').css({
        'margin-left' : -$('#search-box').outerWidth( true )
    });
})

$("li").on("click", function(){
    $("#search-box").val($(this).text());
    $('#myUL').hide();
    // myFunction(); You can put this here if you want to search right after a user clicked
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional script with a click listener on the UL and then a function that handles what you want.

```css
#search-box {
  border-style: none;
}

.divider-border {
  border-right: 2px solid #DFD6D6!important;
  height: auto;
}

.search-radius {
  border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px !important;
  height: 3rem;
  background: #EEEEEE;
}

.btn-default {
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px !important;
  background: #EEEEEE;
}

input[type=search]:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  outline-width: 0 !important;
  background: white !important;
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}

input:focus~.btn-default {
  background: white !important;
}

.btn:focus,
.btn:active {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: url("images/baseline_clear_black_18dp.png");
}

.results {
  /* Remove default list styling */
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.results li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL {
  display: none;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  /* Add a search icon to input */
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  /* Position the search icon */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* Do not repeat the icon image */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full-width */
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Increase font-size */
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  /* Add some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Add a grey border */
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  /* Add some space below the input */
}

#myUL {
  /* Remove default list styling */
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Add a border to all links */
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  /* Grey background color */
  padding: 12px;
  /* Add some padding */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Remove default text underline */
  font-size: 18px;
  /* Increase the font-size */
  color: black;
  /* Add a black text color */
  display: block;
  /* Make it into a block element to fill the whole list */
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
  /* Add a hover effect to all links, except for headers */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Bootstrap css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Our css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Emails View</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <section class="col-10" id="content">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Searchbar -->
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="input-group mt-4">
            <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
              <ul id="myUL" class="dropdown-menu col-12" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>

            <input type="search" class="form-control search-radius" onkeyup="myFunction()" name="search-template" placeholder="Search or select template " id="search-box">
            <span class="divider-border"></span>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>

          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /Searchbar -->

      </div>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <script>
        function myFunction() {
          // Declare variables
          var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
          input = document.getElementById('search-box');
          filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
          ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
          li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

          // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
          for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
              li[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
              li[i].style.display = "none";
            }
          }
        }
      </script>
      <script>
        $('#search-box').on('input', function() {
          $('#myUL').css('display', $(this).val() !== '' ? 'block' : 'none')
        });
      </script>

      <script>
        $('button').click(function() { // on a click on botton
          $('#myUL').show(); // show the div with the search results
          $('#myUL').css({
            'margin-left': -$('#search-box').outerWidth(true)
          });
        })
      </script>
      
      <script>
      /**
      * Here is what is new
      */
        $('#myUL').on('click', function(e) {
          let val = e.target.text();
          $('#search-box').val(val);
          $(this).css('display', 'none');
        })
      </script>
```